# Problems with return value of ajax call

Tags: ajax

I have problems with an ajax call and I think the return value is not returned properly.

I have a index.html page which loads 2 javascript files:

- index.js : For dynamic GUI stuff on index.html
- application.js : Makes an ajax call (uses Javascript module pattern)

## index.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(ApplicationModule.getEventById(123));  // undefined if I use return result[0];
})
```

## application.js

```
var ApplicationModule = (function () {
    // return "foo"; this works in index.html ("foo")
    function getEventById(id) {
        // ajax call returns a json object (list of {"title":"<the title>"} objects)
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            url: "/api/v1/eventtool/" + id,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result[0]);  // works fine -> {"title":"my title"}
                return result[0];  // does not work in index.html (undefined)
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        getEventById : getEventById
    };

})(ApplicationModule || {});
```

If I uncomment the line [ return "foo" ], everything works as expected and I see "foo" at the console.
If I comment this line to execute the ajax call I get "undefined". Why?

Is there something wrong with my ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

returning the value doesn't work, you should specify an element with DOM, like this: `$("#el").html(result[0]);`

Comment: But I need to call this getEventById() function a couple of times on other pages (in other .js files) so I want to return a object that can be used in other .js files.

Comment: in that case you can call the function on the html element and pass it's id to the function, the in the function you can do whatever you want on that element,like this:`onclick="getEventByID(ID)"`. now you have the element id in the function.

Comment: Hm...then I have to re-think my application design as I dont want to modify the dom with this ajax call but return an object whose attributes I can access.

Comment: sure, i hope it was useful,if it was, check the up arrow key so other users can use your question properly.

Comment: And there is not a way to return something from the ajax call so it can be re-used ?

Comment: @user3515612 what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, how can you return an object from an ajax call to another function?
I've googled a bit to find an answer because I've thought there must be a solution using callbacks and promises.
A good resource about this is:
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch1.md

Answer (score 0):

my final solution using fetch and promises:

**application.js**

```
function getEventById(id) {
    return fetch(myurl)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(myJson) {                
            return myJson[0];
        });
}
```

**index.html**

```
const check_event = ApplicationModule.getEventById(123);
// console.log(check_event); // Promise {<pending>}
// [[PromiseStatus]] "resolved"
// [[PromiseValue]]  {"title":"my title"}
check_event.then(function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // {"title":"my title"}
});
```